# Draw after inputting Path value from a file

Tags: android, path, ondraw

I am now trying to find a way to save my Path and load it again when I restart the app.

I can retrieve the values of the Path by retrieving it from the file. But unfortunately, the path is not shown in my app.

I have tried to use `invalidate()` to refresh the view again but nothing changes.

Can you give me some advice to solve this problem?

Many thanks.

```
// used to determine whether user moved a finger enough to draw again
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 10;

private Bitmap bitmap; // drawing area for display or saving

private Canvas bitmapCanvas; // used to draw on bitmap

private CustomPaint mPaint; // use to draw bitmap onto screen
private CustomPaint mPaintScreen;
// private CustomPath mPath; // used to draw lines onto bitmap

// private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
// private ArrayList<Path> r_paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
private ArrayList<CustomPath> undonePaths = new ArrayList<CustomPath>();

private int patternID;

private float[] intervals = new float[] { 50.0f, 20.0f };
private float phase = 0;
private DashPathEffect dashPathEffect;

private byte[] byteArray;

private ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

private Map<CustomPath, Integer> colorsMap = new HashMap<CustomPath, Integer>();
private Map<CustomPath, Float> widthsMap = new HashMap<CustomPath, Float>();

public static int selectedcolor;
public static float selectedwidth;

private CustomPath customPath;

private ArrayList<CustomPath> cPath = new ArrayList<CustomPath>();

// DoodleView constructor initializes the DoodleView
public DoodleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs); // pass context to View's constructor
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);

    dashPathEffect = new DashPathEffect(intervals, phase);

    // set the initial display settings for the painted line
    mPaint = new CustomPaint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true); // smooth edges of drawn line
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE); // default color is black
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); // solid line
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5); // set the default line width
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND); // rounded line ends

    bitmapCanvas = new Canvas();
    customPath = new CustomPath();
    mPaintScreen = new CustomPaint();
    selectedcolor = mPaint.getColor();
    selectedwidth = mPaint.getStrokeWidth();

    // paths.add(mPath);

} // end DoodleView constructor

// Method onSizeChanged creates BitMap and Canvas after app displays
@Override
public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldW, oldH);
    Resources res = getResources();
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.court);

    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    bitmapCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
} // end method onSizeChanged

// clear the painting
public void clear() {
    System.out.println(colorsMap);
    System.out.println(widthsMap);
    System.out.println(cPath);
    cPath.clear();
    invalidate();
} // end method clear

// set the painted line's color
public void setDrawingColor(int color) {
    mPaint.setColor(color);
} // end method setDrawingColor

// return the painted line's color
public int getDrawingColor() {
    return mPaint.getColor();
} // end method getDrawingColor

// set the painted line's width
public void setLineWidth(int width) {
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(width);
} // end method setLineWidth

// return the painted line's width
public int getLineWidth() {
    return (int) mPaint.getStrokeWidth();
} // end method getLineWidth

// public void settingClear() {
// mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK); // default color is black
// mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5); // set the default line width
// }

public byte[] getBitmap() {

    Bitmap bmp = takeScreenshot();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    return byteArray;
}

public void setPathPattern(int pattern) {
    patternID = pattern;
    if (patternID == 2)
        mPaint.setPathEffect(dashPathEffect);
}

private float mX, mY;

private PointF startPoint;

private PointF endPoint;

// called each time this View is drawn
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, mPaintScreen);
    for (int p = 0; p < cPath.size(); p++) {
        mPaint.setColor(colorsMap.get(cPath.get(p)));
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(widthsMap.get(cPath.get(p)));

        canvas.drawPath(cPath.get(p), mPaint);

    }
    mPaint.setColor(selectedcolor);

    canvas.drawPath(customPath, mPaint);
    System.out.print(cPath);

} // end method onDraw

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    // undonePaths.clear();
    customPath.reset();
    // paths.add(mPath);
    customPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
    if (patternID == 1) {
        startPoint = new PointF(x, y);
        endPoint = new PointF();
    }

}

private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (patternID == 0 || patternID == 2) {
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            customPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    } else {
        customPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
        // mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        endPoint.x = x;
        endPoint.y = y;
    }

}

private void touch_up() {
    if (patternID == 0) {
        customPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // // commit the path to our offscreen
        // bitmapCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

        // kill this so we don't double draw
        cPath.add(customPath);
        // r_paths.add(mPath);

        colorsMap.put(customPath, selectedcolor);
        widthsMap.put(customPath, selectedwidth);

        customPath = new CustomPath();
        customPath.reset();
        invalidate();
    } else if (patternID == 1) {
        customPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        float deltaX = endPoint.x - startPoint.x;
        float deltaY = endPoint.y - startPoint.y;
        float frac = (float) 0.1;

        float point_x_1 = startPoint.x
                + ((1 - frac) * deltaX + frac * deltaY);
        float point_y_1 = startPoint.y
                + ((1 - frac) * deltaY - frac * deltaX);

        float point_x_2 = endPoint.x;
        float point_y_2 = endPoint.y;

        float point_x_3 = startPoint.x
                + ((1 - frac) * deltaX - frac * deltaY);
        float point_y_3 = startPoint.y
                + ((1 - frac) * deltaY + frac * deltaX);

        customPath.moveTo(point_x_1, point_y_1);
        customPath.lineTo(point_x_2, point_y_2);
        customPath.lineTo(point_x_3, point_y_3);
        customPath.lineTo(point_x_1, point_y_1);
        customPath.lineTo(point_x_1, point_y_1);

        bitmapCanvas.drawPath(customPath, mPaint);
        cPath.add(customPath);
        // r_paths.add(mPath);
        customPath = new CustomPath();
        endPoint.x = mX;
        endPoint.y = mY;
    } else if (patternID == 4) {
        customPath.moveTo(mX, mY);
        customPath.lineTo(mX + 15, mY + 15);
        customPath.lineTo(mX - 15, mY - 15);
        customPath.lineTo(mX + 15, mY - 15);
        customPath.lineTo(mX - 15, mY + 15);
        cPath.add(customPath);
        // r_paths.add(mPath);
        customPath = new CustomPath();

    } else {
        bitmapCanvas.drawCircle(mX, mY, 20, mPaint);
        cPath.add(customPath);
        // r_paths.add(mPath);
        customPath = new CustomPath();
    }
}

public void onClickUndo() {
    if (cPath.size() > 0) {
        undonePaths.add(cPath.remove(cPath.size() - 1));
        invalidate();
    } else {

    }
    // toast the user
}

public void onClickRedo() {
    if (undonePaths.size() > 0) {
        cPath.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size() - 1));
        invalidate();
    } else {

    }
    // toast the user
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        selectedcolor = mPaint.getColor();
        selectedwidth = mPaint.getStrokeWidth();
        touch_start(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        touch_move(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        touch_up();
        invalidate();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

// save the current image to the Gallery
public void saveImage() {
    // use "Doodlz" followed by current time as the image file name
    String fileName = "Doodlz" + System.currentTimeMillis();

    // create a ContentValues and configure new image's data
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaColumns.TITLE, fileName);
    values.put(MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");

    // get a Uri for the location to save the file
    Uri uri = getContext().getContentResolver().insert(
            Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

    try {
        // get an OutputStream to uri
        OutputStream outStream = getContext().getContentResolver()
                .openOutputStream(uri);
        Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
        // copy the bitmap to the OutputStream
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);

        // flush and close the OutputStream
        outStream.flush(); // empty the buffer
        outStream.close(); // close the stream

        View rootView = findViewById(R.id.doodleView).getRootView();
        rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        // display a message indicating that the image was saved
        Toast message = Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                R.string.doodlz_message_saved, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        message.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, message.getXOffset() / 2,
                message.getYOffset() / 2);
        message.show(); // display the Toast
    } // end try
    catch (IOException ex) {
        // display a message indicating that the image was saved
        Toast message = Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                R.string.doodlz_message_error_saving, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        message.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, message.getXOffset() / 2,
                message.getYOffset() / 2);
        message.show(); // display the Toast
    } // end catch
} // end method saveImage

public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
    View rootView = findViewById(R.id.doodleView).getRootView();
    rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    return rootView.getDrawingCache();
}

public void ClearCache() {
    View rootView = findViewById(R.id.doodleView).getRootView();
    rootView.destroyDrawingCache();
}

public void savePreviousPlan(File plan) {
    try {

        ObjectOutputStream save = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(plan));
        System.out.println(colorsMap);
        save.writeObject(cPath);
        save.writeObject(colorsMap);
        save.writeObject(widthsMap);
        save.flush();
        save.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void loadPreviousPlan(File plan) {
    try {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        ObjectInputStream save = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                plan));
        ArrayList<CustomPath> loadpath = new ArrayList<CustomPath>();
        Map<CustomPath, Integer> loadcolorsMap = new HashMap<CustomPath, Integer>();
        Map<CustomPath, Float> loadwidthsMap = new HashMap<CustomPath, Float>();
        // clear();
        loadpath = (ArrayList<CustomPath>) save.readObject();
        loadcolorsMap = (HashMap<CustomPath, Integer>) save.readObject();
        loadwidthsMap = (HashMap<CustomPath, Float>) save.readObject();
        System.out.println(loadpath);
        for (int i = 0; i < loadpath.size(); i++) {
            cPath.add(loadpath.get(i));
        }
        // colorsMap.clear();
        // widthsMap.clear();
        colorsMap.putAll(loadcolorsMap);
        widthsMap.putAll(loadwidthsMap);

        //postInvalidate();

        // bitmapCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, mPaintScreen);
        // for (CustomPath p : cPath) {
        // mPaint.setColor(colorsMap.get(p));
        // mPaint.setStrokeWidth(widthsMap.get(p));
        //
        // bitmapCanvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
        // System.out.println("test");
        // }

        save.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: do you want to save the path of the image and retrieve it on when the app is launched again??

Comment: No. I want to save the android.graphics.Path and retrieve it. CustomPath is a class which extends Path @Chandra